# Ionic File Chooser URL issue

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am using this plugin for getting files
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser/

When I select a PDF file from **Downloads** folder it is giving me a `URI` like `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1015`

But if i select another file like *ZIP* or *PNG* it resolves to a suitable path

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Fwws.zip

content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Fopacity.png
```

How do I get the path from a file in the form of `file://…`.

I have tried the following approaches with no success yet:

```
FilePath.resolveNativePath
```

and

```
normalizeURL
```

UPDATE:

Imports

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FileChooser } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser'
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';
```

Code for file chooser:

```
  getAndroidFile() {

    this.fileChooser.open()
      .then(uri => {
        console.log("uri", uri);
        this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(uri).then((files) => {
          console.log("files", files);
        }).catch((error) => { console.log("error", error) });
        (<any>window).FilePath.resolveNativePath(uri, (result) => {
          this.nativepath = result;
          console.log("nativepath", this.nativepath);
        }, (err) => {
          console.log("err", err);
        })
      })
  }
```

I have used it as Aaron suggested:

```
this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(uri).then((files)=>{
          console.log("files",files);
        }).catch((error) => { console.log("error", error) });
```

It still returns as:

```
filesystem: FileSystem {name: "content", root: DirectoryEntry}
fullPath: "/com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1015"
isDirectory: false
isFile: true
name: "1015"
nativeURL: "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1015"
```

Which is the original url.

UPDATE 2:

```
getBase64Content(nativepath) {
let path = nativepath.substring(0, nativepath.lastIndexOf('/'));
let filename = nativepath.substring(nativepath.lastIndexOf('/'), nativepath.length);
filename = filename.replace("/", "");
console.log("path", path);
console.log("filename", filename);
this.file.readAsDataURL(path, filename)
  .then(content => {
    console.log('content1', content);
    //this will be passed to web API 
    this.base64content = content;

  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("err", err);
  })
```

}

This base64 content is sent overthe  to server via api and they convert it back to file.

UPDATE 3:
Sorry for late reply, really busy with another project.
Answers for Koken:

How are you testing this thing? 
What command are you using for the execution?
ionic cordova run android
(I check the values by remote debugging using chrome.)

Android emulator? Android device?
Android Device. Redmi note 5 pro(MIUI 10, Android 8.1).

Also... what are the next steps after selecting the file?
This base64 content is sent over to server via api and they convert it back to file.

Hope you guys can help me. With code given. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl` from the `FileManager` Plugin

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/#resolveLocalFilesystemUrl

Comment: Hi Aaron I have done as you said but getting same path as response. You can check my answer here [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/file-chooser-url-issue/142756/3)